# PHP Search function returning results that have numbers as a default

Tags: php, search

I am currently having an issue with my php code below for a search function on my website. Due to the array, it continues to return results (as well as the searched result) which contain numbers in the title, description or keywords.

Is there a better way I could be getting results and not returning default results that contain numbers in my database?

Live example http://www.proimagehub.com/videolist.php the search to the right.

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['search'])){
  if(isset($_GET['go'])){
  if(preg_match("/^[ a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $_POST['sitesearch'])){
  $words = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sitesearch']);   
$arraySearch = explode(" ", protect($words));       
$countSearch = count($arraySearch);
$a = 0;
$query = "SELECT * FROM tutorials WHERE ";
$quote = "'";
while ($a < $countSearch)
{
  $query = $query."keywords || description || title LIKE $quote%$arraySearch[$a]%$quote ";

  $a++;
  if ($a < $countSearch)
  {
    $query = $query." || ";
    }   
  }

  //-run  the query against the mysql query function
  $result=mysql_query($query) or die(error);
  $counters = mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo "<h3>Search Results for: ".$words."</h3>";
    echo "<h5>Total Matching Results: ".$counters."</h5>";  

  //-create  while loop and loop through result set
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $Keywords=$row['keywords'];
            $Description=$row['description'];
            $Title=$row['title'];
            $ID=$row['id'];
            $Rank = $row["rank"];
            $Type = $row["type"];
            $Image = $row['img'];
            $ImageNumber = $row['imgnum'];
            $Video = $row['video'];
  //-display the result of the array
?>
```

Comment: First, you should not use mysql_*, it's deprecated. Use mysqli_* instead. Can you clarify your question? what's not working?

Comment: Thanks. My script works fine and returns the searched results however it seems to by default return anything that it is searching for that contains numbers either in the description or the title. i.e. if I search for a word that doesn't exist it will still return 3 results as each one contain numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the query part

```
... WHERE keywords || description || title LIKE '...'
```

is not working as expected. `||` is a [logical OR operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or). It is not some kind of semantic OR operator which will automatically be combined with the `LIKE` operator in the way you hope.

You have to use the LIKE operator on the individual fields like:

```
WHERE
    keywords LIKE '...' OR
    description LIKE '...' OR
    title LIKE '...'
```